# Create a user with php

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04

I want to make a script, which creates a user in ubuntu (e.g. `$ adduser FIRSTNAME.LASTNAME` and home directory `/home/FIRSTNAME.LASTNAME/`)

You probably wonder "Why would he want that?". Well, I want to make a mail-server using `Maildir`.

Now comes the problem. This command has to run with SuperUser rights, how do I do this?

Is there actually an easier way to create a user? And it has to be triggered from php (apache) as when the user creates an account in the website it should also create the home-dir

**EDIT:**

As many people still don't understand, let me give you an example

1. A user goes to `https://example.com/register.php`
2. He wished his email would be `hans.peter@example.com` and enters also other information which aren't important now.
3. He clicks on submit and the PHP server running Apache handels the information
4. The server create a new e-Mail in `Dovecot` called `hans.peter@example.com` and creates a directory called `/home/hans.peter/Maildir/`

My problem is on point 4, as everything has to be triggered by **PHP AND SUPERUSER**. And not to forget, my user with root rights (called `user`) is password protected

Comment: You Google for "run shell commands as sudo with PHP" and then you read up on all potential security issues this might have.

Comment: shell_exec(); you need this.

Comment: Make damned sure you're sanitizing `FIRSTNAME` and `LASTNAME`. :-p

Comment: i updated the problem, read the last lines

Comment: there's plenty of ways of creating mailboxes without making that user a full-blown system account user.

Comment: The point is, he creates an account on my website, THEN, the it will create an Database entry and the home-directory

Comment: You can configure apache to run as admin, and this would accomplish what you're asking for. Likewise if you're trying to run something in php that you would normally type out in bash, `shell_exec()` works... but be warned that apache running as root in conjunction with your php scripts calling `shell_exec`s _screams_ security vulnerabilities...

Comment: isn't it possible to run only this small code with su?

Comment: and FIRSTNAME.LASTNAME can only be everything between `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_-.`. They are the only character to create the mail (FIRSTNAME.LASTNAME@something.com)

Comment: You could do [disclaimer - security warning] `shell_exec('sudo bash mycommand.sh')`. That said, I think there might be a better way to accomplish whatever you're trying to do. Regarding mailing users, you can probably do that without creating accounts for them on the server box. Usually web frameworks and user databases handle that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the `shell_exec` command. this command let's you execute `unix` commands from PHP.

```
shell_exec('adduser ...');
```

For more information about the `shell_exec()` command take a look at the documentation.

#### Documentation

- [shell_exec() - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

Comment: `adduser` would have to run with root-right, otherwise it wouldn't create the directory. But my Root user is password protected, so wouldn't it make it problems when trying to execute `sudo` in php?

Comment: and i don't think that shell_exec automaticly has root-rights

Comment: StackOverflow is here to help in questions about programming. For `unix/linux` and permission issues I would like to suggest http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: that's only half correct ... :| ... it HAS to run over php, i will try to exlplain it again ...

Comment: If you want to solve it using PHP you can always use a cron job to create the users.